# String combination with all synonyms

Tags: java, recursion

I have a String where some words are having some synonyms.

e.g. String: A B C D

and words with synonyms are:

A => AX, AY, AZ

B => BX, BY

C => CX, CY, CZ

I have to find different string combinations with these synonyms.

The output of the above String should be:

AX, BX, CX

AX, BX, CY

AX, BX, CZ

AX, BY, CX

AX, BY, CY

AX, BY, CZ

---

and repeat the same process from AY of key A and so on...

I have a wordSynonymList that contains a list of Maps. and Each map contains a Key that is a word (A) and a value that is list of synonyms of that word.

e.g. [{A=[AX, AY, AZ]}, {B=[BX, BY]}.....]

I am trying using the nested loop with the number of loops = number of words having synonyms. But words with synonyms are not fixed.

How can I do this using recursion?

**## Edit Part ##**

I am trying to achieve this using nested for loops, but I think it's not possible because words is not fixed.

for(Map> wordSynonym :  wordSynonymList) {

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> words : wordSynonym.entrySet()) {

                String a = words.getKey(); //gives me A

                for (String synonym : words.getValue()) {
                    //gives me all synonym of A
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: You can do that by starting to try. Then, when you have written some code, and you can't get that to work, then you are welcome to ask a question within the scope of this community.

Comment: @GhostCat Hi Sorry I am new to this community so, I don't know the basic rules. As you give me a suggestion I edit my question. I am requesting you to please take a look at my edit part.

Comment: Beyond that, I think you want to search for *permutations*.

Comment: Yes, Sentance permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not very efficient, but you can craft a simple function that does that:

```
public static Object getKeyFromValue(Map hm, Object value) {
    for (Iterator iter = hm.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
      Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
      if (e.contains(value)) {
        return e.getKey();
      }
    }
return null;
}
```

I have not tested if it works but it's along those lines